# How to create a function to select specific array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that is called by multiple different buttons, and that selects a specific array depending on which button called the function.

For example:

If a button with `id="Anterior"` called the function, the function selects array named `plusAnterior`:

```
var plusAnterior = ["p", "b", "t", "d", "ɸ", "β", "f", "v", "θ", "ð", "s", "z", "m", "n", "l", "ɬ", "r", "ɾ"];
var minusAnterior = ["c", "ɟ", "k", "g", "ʃ", "ʒ", "x", "ɣ", "ɲ", "ŋ", "j", "w", "ʡ", "h"];
var toAdd = [];

function addFeature(featureId) {
  if (activeFeatures === 0) {
    toAdd = // plusAnterior called here
  }
}
```

The problem is, I cannot simply do `toAdd = plusAnterior` because I want my function to work for any button pressed. I thought of doing something like `getElementById("plus" + featureId)`, but I can't since the arrays I'm trying to select are not in my HTML.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: @EmilieHass why would you call getElementById to retrieve a javascript data structure? getElementById are stricly for DOM elements.

Comment: @andreihondrari   i think, he said the same thing in last sentence.

Comment: @ahmet_y yes I know, but I still don't understand why would he do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, you can use an `object` almost as a **key/value** array.

```
var testObject = {
  featureId_a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // etc
  featureId_b: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // etc
}
```

Then we can return it with your method like so...

```
function addFeature(featureId) {
  return testObject[featureId];
}
```

I think this is what you mean. Otherwise, you could use a 2D array and select based on the index. But it depends on your data really the best option.

For brevity and some sanitization, you should, of course, check the object for the property.

```
if(testObject.hasOwnProperty(featureId)){
  return testObject[featureId];
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I was searching for!

Thank you very much!